# Can I use a 2019 27" iMac as a display for a Mid 2014 Retina 13" MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, imac

The iMac is running Mojave, the MacBook is on High Sierra.

Will the Apple Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) to Thunderbolt 2 adapter + a thunderbolt 2 cable work?

Comment: This question clearly shows lack of research... Next time please google at least once before posting a question.

Comment: As a second monitor or just as a mirrored display? I ask because you can screen share if you just want to mirror the displays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NO**

The [Apple documentation](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-an-imac-as-a-display-mh30822/mac) clearly states that this is not possible with iMacs newer than mid 2014 (iMacs with a Retina Display).

> *Note:* Target Display Mode isn’t supported on iMac models with Retina display. Only iMac (27-inch, Late 2009), iMac (27-inch, Mid 2010), and iMac (Mid 2011 to Mid 2014) support Target Display Mode.

[Apple Community](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250406000) states it as well.

Comment: No, mid 2014 is still supported. At least thats what it says on Apples docs... Edited the answer anyway

Comment: Yes, you're right. I think we're both saying the same thing, yet I was imprecise in the beginning: iMacs up to mid 2014 will work, after that (Retina models) it's not possible to run them in target disk mode.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, I deleted my comments.

Comment: No problem, errare human est ;)